# Fill remaining input text fields with focused value

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have 3-4 products and their prices in table format.
My page looks like,
[image]

And my code looks like,

```
<table>
      <tr *ngFor="let val of prods">
        <td class="sea">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val.key" />
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let sale of val.sales">
          <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="sale.value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

ie a variable is binded to each text box.

Now what I need is 
I have to create a new shotcut to auto fill all values using the value from the current focussed element (by row).
So if I enter 100 on the 1st column of 1st row and then press F2,
All the values in the first row should be replaced with 100.

I am able to listen to the keypress event  and get the value of the current focussed element using the following code,

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === 'F2') {
      if (document.activeElement['value']) {

      }
    }
  }
```

But don't know how to fill this value to all sibling input fields.
I know it is a bad idea to use jQuery inside angular. 
Any help to solve this in angular way?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your code but did you try to fill in val.sales with the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is searching solution for similar situation.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let val of prods">
  <td class="sea">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val.key" />
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let sale of val.sales ; let k = index">
      <input (keydown)="onKeydown($event, k, val )"  type="text" [(ngModel)]="sale.value" />
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>


onKeydown(event, k, arr) {
  if (event.code === 'F2' && k === 0) {
    if (document.activeElement['value']) {
      const elemval = document.activeElement['value'];
      for (const elmnt of arr.sales) {
        elmnt.value = elemval;
      }
    }
  }
}
```